# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Multi container Docker app with error "Connection Refused"

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i tried to run docker multiple container app on ElasticBeanstalk, Health is OK, logs are fine
i have running 2 apps in nodejs in docker its working fine in local enviroment but when i upload my code zip file on ElasticBeanstalk everything is fine except for the end result
which is "Connection refused" error
i am very new on AWS and dont know what to do
or what is the actual proccess to do that

i tried to add many permission on role associated with that enviroment
checking all logs which are fine
thats all i can do and know about it